# Enable SSL support for pgsql

Tags: php, postgresql, ssl, wampserver

In `phpinfo()`, under the `pgsql` section, `SSL support` is currently **disabled**:

[image]

How can I enable it?

Comment: Where did you install your server with PHP from?

Comment: Read this: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/web-site-flexibility-with-security-postgresql-apache-php-and-ssl/

Answer (score 2):

This is about SSL support of Pgsql really.

The library libpq is probably not compiled with SSL support.
Have you built the package of pgsql and/or libpg yourself?
If so, you can enable it by compiling with the option --with-openssl

If you did not compile it yourself, try to find a package with SSL built in.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to determine “How your current PostgreSQL extension has been compiled?” (Is is compiled into the *main PHP executable or Loadable extension*).

#### Determining compilation of current PGSQL extension:

1. View contents of your php.ini file
2. Find a line something like ‘extension=php_pgsql.so’ (should be php_pgsql.dylib)

> > If you found line like this then your extension is a *loadable module*. If it has a ***semicolon*** in front, then your extension is into the main *PHP executable*.

If, it is a loadable extension then you can *search on the web* with the hope that someone has previously compiled the PGSQL extension with SSL Support for particular OS. If your extension is into the main PHP executable, then find OS distribution, which comes with SSL enabled.

If you’re still unable to solve your problem, then you need to build/compile the PostgreSQL extension against a version of libpq that has in turn been compiled with SSL support.

***Hope it helps!***

Answer (score 0):

In one of your databases (eg. the "postgres" administration db), issue `show ssl;`. If it returns "off", then edit your postgresql.conf and change the line "ssl = off" to "ssl = on" and reload your config (issue "select pg_reload_conf()" as the superuser).

More details on ssl support can be found in the docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ssl-tcp.html

Comment: This is SSL support in PHP for the pgsql extension, not server/database support.

Comment: It's still good to make sure the underlying database has it enabled before banging one's head against a system built on top of it. (If `show ssl;` was false, one might also check that `hostssl` is in use in the `pg_hba.conf` file.  Just saying.)